# Не работает влажность в pyowm

Tags: python, pyowm

```
place = input("Укажите город: ")

owm = pyowm.OWM("token", language="ru")
observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather()
temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
wih = w. get_wind()['speed']
humi = get_humidity()['humidity']

print("______________________")
print ("\nГород: "+ place + "\n----------------------" +"\nТемпература: " + 
str(temp) + " C"+"\nСкорость ветра: " + str(wi`введите сюда код`h) +" м/с" + "\nВлажность: " + str(humi) + "мм")

input()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По идее после ввода города в консоль должны выводиться температура, скорость ветра и влажность.
До того как добавил влажность всё работало правильно, но с ней выдаёт ошибку.
Как лечить?

Comment: Ошибку, пожалуйста, в вопрос в виде текста. Плюс, ошибка ведь в `get_humidity()['humidity']`, тогда добавьте в вопрос текст функции

Comment: может, потому что get_humidity - это метод объекта `w`? и должно быть `humi = w.get_humidity()` ?

Comment: На сколько я знаю, у pyowm есть обычный API и Pro API. Если вы используете обычный, то скорее всего в нем не предусмотрена влажность, а есть она только в Pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы вызываете `get_humidity()` как самостоятельную функцию, а не метод класса.
Замените ваше

```
humi = get_humidity()['humidity']
```

На

```
humi = w.get_humidity()['humidity']
```